# What is the purpose of requiring a data type specification of the returned value in a function definition or prototype? Type casting?

Tags: c, function, casting

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int demo_function(float a);

int main(void) 
{
  
  int b;
  float fraction_number = 3.15f;
  b = demo_function(fraction_number);
  printf("The number returned is %d", b);
  return 0;
}

int demo_function(float a)
{
  float c;
  c = a;
  printf("The number passed is %.2f \n", c);
  return c;
}
```

The output is:

`The number passed is 3.15`

`The number returned is 3`

From this little test code, it seems like *actual purpose* of writing `int` as the data type of `demo_function`'s returned value is to **type cast**.

Firstly, is that the *correct* interpretation of what is going on?

Secondly, why does the compiler actually need this information? (Or perhaps a better question is, "How does the compiler *use* this information?"). Specifically, if the compiler sees that variable `b` is declared as an `int`, why does it need to *explicitly* know that the returned value is of type `int`?

If we end up storing the returned value of variable `c` into `b`, what issues would arise if the compiler did NOT require the explicit mention that the returned value is of type `int`? Would there be information loss as the `float c` variable tries to get *squished* into the smaller memory allocated `int b` variable?

Thanks!

Comment: The purpose isn't to type cast, that's a side effect of what you're doing (returning a float for an int function). Remember what happens in assembly when a function returns; usually, any return values are pushed to the stack, and then the program jumps back to the instruction after the call. When the compiler pops the return value off the stack, it needs to know its size, type, etc. to handle the data properly.

Comment: No, the purpose of writing the type is so that whoever uses the function knows the type. There is no cast in there. A cast is an *explicit* type conversion. If the compiler sees `x = y`, it needs to know types of **both** x **and** y. More generally, when the compiler sees *any* value being used *in any manner whatsoever*, it needs to know its type. Without this information, the operation cannot be interpreted correctly, or even pronounced valid.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type_checking

Comment: You question is quite broad and contains several issues each worth a whole chapter if this were a book. -- However, each value has a type, and so even the return value of a function needs a type. If you don't provide one, the compiler assumes `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a practical matter, the compiler needs to know what type a function returns because it needs to know how to interpret the bits a function returns and it needs to know where those bits are.

Suppose that when a function returns, the register used for the return value contains 0x80. If the function is supposed to return an 8-bit `unsigned char`, then the return value is 128. If the function is supposed to return an 8-bit two’s complement `signed char`, then the return value is −128. Knowing the type is necessary to know the interpretation of the bits.

In many systems, a function that returns an integer is supposed to put the bits in a certain *general register* of the processor, but a function that returns a floating-point value is supposed to put the bits in a certain *floating-point register*. In this case, the caller needs to know the return type of the function in order to know where the bits of the return value are.

At a more abstract level, the compiler needs to know the return type of the function so that it can interpret the expression the function call appears in. Consider that, in C, the expression `5 / 4` performs integer division with truncation and produces 1, but the expression `5. / 4` performs floating-point division and produces 1.25. So, in the expression `f(x) / 4`, the compiler needs to know what type `f` returns so that it knows whether to perform integer division of floating-point division.

For another example, suppose `f` returns a pointer, and the program uses `y = *f(x)`. To execute this code, the compiler has to take the value returned by `f` and use it as an address to fetch something from memory. But what does it fetch? Does the address point to a one-byte `char`, an eight-byte `double`, or a 100-byte structure? The compiler needs to know the type of the pointer returned by `f` so that it knows what type of object it points to.

> From this little test code, it seems like *actual purpose* of writing `int` as the data type of `demo_function`'s returned value is to **type cast**.

The primary purpose is as described above. The fact that the value in a `return` statement is converted to the return type of the function is a secondary effect; it is merely a convenience of the language, not a necessary effect. (The implicit conversion is not necessary because we could effect the conversion by specifying it explicitly.)

Also note that a *cast* is an explicit operator. It is not the operation. For example, `+` and `*` are operators; they are things that appear in source code that say we want to do certain operations. The actual operations are addition and multiplication. Similarly, a cast is a type name in parentheses; it is some text that appears in source code that specifies we want to perform a conversion.